# Moving ubuntu partition to another drive

Tags: partitioning, gparted, clonezilla

I installed a new ssd drive in my computer and want to move my current ubuntu partition to that drive.
I plan to use clonezilla to move the partition but I have a few questions that remain:

When I check my current ubuntu partition using Gparted, I find not 1 but 3 and that is where I am unsure how I should handle them: sdc4 which is the parent of sdc5 (ext4) and sdc6 (swap).

Another thing that puzzles me is that only the partitions sdc5 and sdc6 shows up with the command blkid on the terminal. Sdc4 is not there.

So what partition should be cloned?

Please see attached screen shots.
[image: gparted]
[image: blkid]

Comment: That is the 40 year old MBR(msdos) partitioning which has an extended partition which is just a container for logical partitions. Better to use the newer gpt partitioning, but that requires a new install & restore from your backups. Windows requires MBR for BIOS installs. Ubuntu can install in BIOS or UEFI mode to gpt drives.Microsoft has required UEFI with gpt partitioning since 2012 for vendor installs.

Comment: @oldfred Just install `grub-efi-amd64`, `rsync` the whole rootfs to the target drive and fix EFI booting (`grub-install`) and it's good to go. I myself have moved Ubuntu across disks multiple times with this workflow.

Comment: Ubuntu will let you install in UEFI boot mode to MBR drive, but should not. Since new drive, best to convert to gpt now. UEFI strongly suggests gpt and Windows requires gpt. You can use gpt with BIOS installs. The only place you need to use MBR is with Windows in BIOS boot mode.

Answer (score 0):

### Moving Ubuntu partition to another drive

Here is a method of copying your Ubuntu to a SSD that will boot in either BIOS or UEFI mode. (This could be handy if you ever upgrade your Windows disk to UEFI).

- Download the mkusb ISO boot template: https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_grub-boot-template-for-uefi-n-bios.img.xz
- Flash the image to the SSD using Rufus, Etcher, mkusb, Disks, dd, etc. This will overwrite everything on the new SSD.

The SSD will now have a 1MB **bios_grub** boot partition and a 250MB **boot,esp** partition and a lot of unformatted space.

- Booting from a Live USB, open GParted and right click copy the ext4 Ubuntu partition from the old drive and right click paste the partition into the unformatted space on the SSD. you will have the option to increase the size of the partition as desired.

There is no need to copy the extended partition and the swap partition can be created new.

- Copy /boot/grub/grub.cfg from Ubuntu on the old disk and paste it into /boot/grub/ in the new boot,esp partition overwriting the one there.
- Edit /boot/grub/grub.cfg in boot,esp to confirm the boot path. ie your `hd0,msdos6` may now be `hd0,gpt3`. I use `Find and Replace` to change all instances of `msdos` to `gpt` in the menuentry.

The new UUID should be the same as the old. You can change the partition UUID on the new SSD using GParted. This is necessary if you plan on keeping both Ubuntus

If there are any doubts when editing grub.cfg you can boot the old Ubuntu and run `sudo update-grub` with the new drive plugged in. This will automatically create a correct new menuentry that can be used when updating the new SSD GRUB. Best to change the UUID as above first.